# REGEXP does not show the right result?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have in the **name** column:

```
3 boxes of frogs
7 boxes of frogs
48 boxes of frogs
```

When I execute:

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name REGEXP "[^1-5] boxes"
```

...the result is:

```
7 boxes of frogs
48 boxes of frogs
```

When I tried:

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name REGEXP "[^1-50] boxes"
```

and

```
SELECT name FROM items WHERE name REGEXP "[^1-48] boxes"
```

...the result is:

```
7 boxes of frogs
48 boxes of frogs
```

and

```
7 boxes of frogs
```

...respectively.

Why won't "3 boxes of frogs" show with `REGEXP "[^1-48] boxes` and others.
The result of `REGEXP "[^1-48] boxes` and `REGEXP "[^1-50] boxes` is so weird.
Can someone explain why?

Comment: If you want SQL to look at the number, then put the number in its own column as you insert the data.

Answer (score 7):

Regex doesn't work like that. You cannot specify numerical range.

> `[]` brackets specifies character sets to match. `^` character inside
>   `[]` means negation = anything outside the specified character set. I
>   assume you wanted to indicate the start of the string which is also
>   marked with `^` but outside of the `[]` part.

- [^1-5] means any character which is not a number between 1 and 5
- [^1-50] means any character which is not a number between 1 and 5 and not 0

### In more details:

**[^1-5] boxes**

`7 boxes of frogs` matches because 7 is not a number between 1 and 5 followed by a spaces and the word boxes

`48 boxes of frogs` matches because 4 doesn't match (regular machine not in the first step) -> 8 is not a number between 1 and 5 followed by a spaces and the word boxes the actual match is: `8 boxes of frogs`

**[^1-48] boxes**

Doesn't match `48 boxes of frogs` because the rules specifies now characters from the set of (1,2,3,4,8) and the string fails on this check.

### Fix your regex

In your case probably you want to use `name regexp '^[0-9]+ boxes of frog'`

Comment: how can i use it for 2 digit numbers?

Comment: @JhomarMaravillas it is not a calculator. There is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3148251) detailing ranges and how to parse them.

Comment: For two digit numbers you can just specify the number of characters: `[0-9]{1-2}` which will match every one or two digit string including `"06"` for example. Or a bit more advanced: `[1-9]?[0-9]` which matches numbers from 0 to 99.